# Transaction gas cost in Foundry `forge` unit tests

Tags: gas, testing, foundry, forge

`forge test` includes support for reporting gas usage by method externally with `--gas-report`.

However, I would like to measure gas usage within a given unit test, which from reading the [documentation](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/tests) doesn't appear to be supported (though the Foundry documentation is sometimes thin).

Is there a way to measure gas usage within `forge` unit tests, ideally via an `assert` for a section of code in a given block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not currently possible to create custom spans for gas reporting in Forge - or rather, Forge does not have a built-in mechanism for this.

The only way you can achieve something similar, is to create your own helper functions that use the `gasleft()` Solidity built-in.

These two functions are taken from [solmate](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/d155ee8d58f96426f57c015b34dee8a410c1eacc/src/test/utils/DSTestPlus.sol):

```
contract GasHelpers {
    string private checkpointLabel;
    uint256 private checkpointGasLeft = 1; // Start the slot warm.

    function startMeasuringGas(string memory label) internal virtual {
        checkpointLabel = label;

        checkpointGasLeft = gasleft();
    }

    function stopMeasuringGas() internal virtual {
        uint256 checkpointGasLeft2 = gasleft();

        // Subtract 100 to account for the warm SLOAD in startMeasuringGas.
        uint256 gasDelta = checkpointGasLeft - checkpointGasLeft2 - 100;

        emit log_named_uint(string(abi.encodePacked(checkpointLabel, " Gas")), gasDelta);
    }
}
```

The function emits an event with the gas used. To see the output of the events you must run your tests with at least double verbosity: `forge test -vv`.

Comment: `gasleft()` is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `forge snapshot --match-test test_name` to run test and it will produce a `gas-snapshot` file where you can see gas usages